# Dynamic menu tree using recursion and getting info from four others mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, menu

I'm trying to make a menu, which will take information from four tables e.g. `pages`, `categories`, `sub-categories` and `articles`.

For example, I want to make a menu which will look something like this:

```
Home
Category 1
   Subcategory 1.2
   Subcategory 1.3
   Subcategory 1.1
Category 2
   Subcategory 2.3
   Subcategory 2.2
   Subcategory 2.1
Subcategory 4.1
   Article 4.1.2
   Article 4.1.3
   Article 4.1.1
Page 2 (Services)
   Page 3 (Service 1)
   Page 4 (Service 2)
   Page 4 (Service 3)
Page 1 (About us)
```

**Database table menu:**

```sql
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+
| id | id_menu | type                | parent_id | order | active |
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | pages               |         0 |     1 |      1 |
|  2 |       1 | sub_categories      |         0 |     2 |      1 |
|  3 |       2 | sub_categories      |         0 |     4 |      1 |
|  4 |       2 | categories          |         0 |     3 |      1 |
|  5 |       3 | sub_categories      |         4 |     1 |      1 |
|  6 |       2 | sub_categories      |         2 |     1 |      1 |
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

***(id_menu stand for id of the type) | (parent_id == 0 stand for root of the menu)***

Menu from the input database should look like this:

```
Page 1
Sub Category 1
   Sub Category 2
Category 2
   Sub Category 3
Sub Category 2
```

I choose to use `type` for the name of the table.
Basically, if I want to take `category 1 (id == 1)` for the second menu item, I'll do something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO `menu` (`id_menu`, `type`, `parent_id`, `order`, `active`) VALUES (`1`, `categories`, `0`, `2`, `1`);
```

I tried a lot of options in PHP to make it, but I get an **infinite** loop or some crazy menu...

How can I make this? Because I've tried various ways and I've not found a relevant solution.

I tried something like this to get just a child of the menu. But then I get an **infinite** loop.

```php
function GetMenuTree($ParentId){
    global $conn;
    $menu = "";
    $MenuData = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM menu where parent_id = ?");
    $MenuData->execute([ $ParentId ]);
    while ($row = $MenuData->fetch()) {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM " . $row[ 'type' ] . " WHERE id = " . $row[ 'id_menu' ];
        $DataForMenu = $conn->prepare($SQL);
        $DataForMenu->execute();
        foreach ($DataForMenu as $value) {
            $menu .= "\n<li><a href='" . $value[ 'title' ] . "'>" . $value[ 'title' ] . "</a>\n";

            $menu .= "\n<ul>" . GetMenuTree($row[ 'id_menu' ]) . "</ul>\n";

            $menu .= "\n</li>\n";
        }
    }
    return $menu;
}
```

Comment: *I wanna to make a menu which one will have look something like this one:*  -- The problem is, that the menu that you **want** doesn't match your sample data .. You should make those match so your **desired output** makes more sense to those of us that would be willing to help.

Comment: I know, but its easy to manage same input data. This is just example of the tabel and desired output

Comment: @Zak I added how should look menu from that database table.

Comment: Your program/data is broken. `Sub-category 4.1` is not behaving as a subcategory. There is no distinction between a category or a subcategory so there's no reason to have them on separate tables. Parent/child relationships can be established using fields on a single `categories` table.

Comment: If I do that, then I'll got naive tree problem again. This is is simplest way for subcategories and categories by my opinion